# Out of memory error VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I'm getting an out of memory error on the following block of code.  Does anyone see an obvious reason why?

Edited the code to show entire block.  eventually this will loop through a directory, but until working I'll only look at one file.

```
Sub Get_BT_Data()
Dim fNameAndPath, data As Variant
Dim j, c, r As Integer

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSM), *.XLSM",     Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath

Sheets("Summary For CDP").Activate
j = Range("A2").Value
c = Range("B2").Value
data = Range("DataRay")

ThisWorkbook.Activate

r = Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown).Row

For i = 7 To r
If Cells(i, 4).Value = j Then
    If Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 1).Value = c Then
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 3).Value = data(9, 20)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 4).Value = data(22, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 7).Value = data(2, 20)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 8).Value = data(15, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 10).Value = data(5, 20)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 11).Value = data(18, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 13).Value = data(3, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 14).Value = data(16, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 16).Value = data(4, 20) + data(6, 20)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 17).Value = data(17, 22) + data(19, 22)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 19).Value = data(7, 20)
        Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, 20).Value = data(20, 22)
    Else
        If i = r Then
            Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        Else
        End If
    End If
Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the maximum value for `r`???

Comment: I have r declared as an integer, the max value could will likely never exceed 400. Do I need to declare as long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking what the value of `r` is

changing `r = Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown).Row` to the below may help.

```
r = Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
```

Same for this line

```
Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Using `XlDown` can be dangerous as you could either miss values if you have blanks in your column, or if you have no data below row 7, then it will return the row at the bottom of the sheet. I suspect this may be happening in this case.

It's usually best practice to start at the bottom of the sheet when you're trying to find the last row of data.

Also,

You should check out how big your `"DataRay"` range is, try substituting it for a proper range rather than a named range,

change `Range("DataRay")` to something like `Range("A1:E500")`

If you want to check the size of your `DataRay` range then you could use the following at the start of your code to debug

```
MsgBox Range("DataRay").Rows.Count & " Rows " & Range("DataRay").Columns.Count & " Columns"
```

Comment: I'm passing a range to the variant array, it's 22 columns by 22 rows, I'll edit my original question with the rest of my code

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I got the same value for r (260) using both ways.  Thank you for the tip about starting from the bottom.  That makes a lot of sense.  I walked it through step by step and I got to i = 50 and then took the breaks off and that's when it errored.  It was before the If i = r statement though.

Comment: @Clouse24 There is another line in your code using `XlDown` try altering that one as well. I didn't see that you had declared `r` as an integer, if you exceeded it's datasize then you would get an `Overflow` error, so it won't be that. Speaking of that `Dim j, c, r As Integer` in that statement `j` and `c` are declared as `Variant`. It should be `Dim j as Integer, c as Integer, r As Integer`

Comment: gave that a shot and actually had to declare a couple of variables as long, but it worked.  thank you so much for your help!